# Sketch $arg(z + i) = arg(z - 1)$. A simple explanation required.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I came across the following question today.

i) Sketch $arg(z + i) = arg(z - 1)$

ii) Sketch $arg(z + i) = arg(z - 1)  + \pi $

Below is my attempt for part i)

Let $ z = x + yi$, therefore

$$ arg(x + yi + i) = arg(x + yi - 1) $$
$$ arg(x + (y + 1)i ) = arg(x - 1 + yi) $$

Since $ arg(z) = tan^{-1} \dfrac{y}{x} $

$$ tan^{-1}\dfrac{y + 1}{x} = tan^{-1}\dfrac{y}{x-1} $$

Taking $tan$ of both sides:

$$ \dfrac{y + 1}{x} = \dfrac{y}{x-1} $$
$$ (y + 1)(x - 1) = xy $$
$$ xy - y + x - 1= xy $$
$$ y = x - 1 $$

So the locus of points is on the line $ y = x - 1 $.  Since $arg(0)$ is undefined, from the original expression $arg(z + i) = arg(z - 1)$, $z \neq i, 1 $.

So my sketch is shown below.

[image: My solution]
However, the solution is the following.

[image: The Correct solution]

Could someone please explain why the region between $ 0 < x < 1 $ is not included.  I have substituted values for $z$, which proves the second image is correct, but I would like a simpler explanation.

For part ii) I'm confused.  The solution is just region between $ 0 < x < 1 $.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\arg z =\arctan(y/x) $ does not hold in general.

Comment: The region $0<x<1$ is located on the top right of $z=-i$ but on the bottom right of $z=1$

Comment: Which branch of $\arg$ do you use?

Comment: I'm not to sure what you mean by 'branch of arg'.

Comment: What does your formula give for the argument of $-1+0\cdot \mathrm i$? Branch of arg: what is the angle of $-1$? Is it $\pi$ or $-\pi$ or $3\pi$ or ...?

Comment: See for example https://complex-analysis.com/content/principal_argument.html.

Comment: In other words, you have to specify the range of the argument function. You can take any half-open interval of length $2\pi$, but the most popular choices are $(-\pi ,\pi]$ and $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: I am assuming where $z = a + bi$, $a>0, b>0$, hence $arg (z) = \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest to see geometrically: the complex number $z-a$ can be thought of as representing the vector that joins $A$ to $Z$, where $A$ and $Z$ are the points represented by the complex numbers $a$ and $z$. Then $\arg(z-a)$ is "the angle from the positive $x$-direction to the direction of the vector represented by $z-a$" and your locus is the set of all $Z$ such that "the angle to the positive $x$-axis made by the vector from $(0,-1)$ to $Z$ is the same as that made by the vector from $(1,0)$ to $Z$".

Now you can see why the 'gap' appears: if Z is on the line $y=x-1$ in that region, the angle to the positive $x$-axis made by the vector from $(0,-1)$ to $Z$ is $\frac{1}{4}\pi$ but that made by the vector from $(1,0)$ to $Z$ is $-\frac{3}{4}\pi$.

In your solution, the problem arises because $\arg(x+iy)$ is not always equal to $\tan^{-1}\dfrac{y}{x}$: for instance $\arg(-1-i)=-\frac{3}{4}\pi$, whereas $\tan^{-1}\dfrac{-1}{-1}=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{1}=\frac{1}{4}\pi$. Because of this, your argument is not reversible: every point on the locus lies on $y=x-1$, but not every point on $y=x-1$ lies on the locus.

For (ii), your argument also gives the line $y=x-1$, because $\tan \theta \equiv \tan (\theta + \pi)$; however, the locus is now the part of the line that was missing in (i) (provided your definition of $\arg z$ is that it always lies in $(-\pi,\pi]$).

If you want a more formal way of doing this, you could rewrite the condition as $$0=\arg(z+i)-\arg(z-1)=\arg\left(\frac{z+i}{z-1}\right)=\arg\left(\frac{(z+i)(z^*-1)}{|z-1|^2}\right).$$ The denominator of this is real and positive, so doesn't affect the argument, so we require $$0=\arg\left((z+i)(z^*-1)\right)=\arg\left((x^2+y^2-x+y)+i(x-1-y)\right).$$ To have zero argument, the imaginary part must be zero, but also, the real part must be positive (else the argument is $\pi$). So $y=x-1$ and $x^2+y^2-x+y=\big(x-\frac{1}{2}\big)^2+\big(y+\frac{1}{2}\big)^2>\frac{1}{2}$. The latter condition excludes the section of the line between $(0, -1)$ and $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $z+i$ and $z-1$ have same argument then $\frac{z+i}{z-1}=k>0$. Hence,
$$z=\frac{k}{k-1}+i\frac{1}{k-1}\text{where $k>0$, $k\neq 1$.}$$
This is the line $y=x-1$ on $\Bbb C$, the segment joining $-i$ and $1$ deleted.